# Where can I learn Spring Boot Security and React with proxy on one port so that it it reloads?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, maven, jwt

I've used pretty much all tutorials on google, seen all github repos. Spent weeks. I'm trying to make an app with a Spring Boot backend with spring Security JWT and React frontend (I don't know if I need webpack for this, some tutorials used it for another level of proxy for some reason, some didn't). I just want to start with something. Something which can be accessed via one port on localhost, which reloads and not gives me 403 unauthorised error instead or even worse, a blank page when I just want to see login page or a page from the menu after authorisation. A Hello World. A Time On Server starter project. Anything. Just so that it reloads and I can build stuff with sense on top of it. Can you please tell where I can find snything?

Comment: you want to have 2 apps (backend and frontend) each of them running on the same port or you want a MVC application?

Comment: Well, maybe, I am not sure how it is called. What I do is I create-react-app, and then use frontend maven plugin. In React I use router. I have a few js and jsx pages there. I want to be able to go to 8080 and see the login page, then authenticate and go to main page. There would be a menu and i would switch. and on those pages i'll be calling rest to display data from Java classes. But while the jwt token is valid I want to be able to reload any page. Now when I reload it shows 403 even though the token is valid

Comment: did you saved the jwt in localstorage or cookies? if you are using restful then you have no session and you have to call your endpoint with the jwt every time

Comment: JWT, local storage, i specifically provided stateless... you can download any ready tutorial of spring boot and react where it is on separate ports, then make it on same port with proxy via pom and package.json. That's what i did... It reloads while it is on different ports and after it doesn't.

Comment: For example I used this one https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-react-fullstack-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-react-jwt-auth-login-logout